# Android WebView doesn't store the cookies

Tags: android, eclipse

seems that Android WebView doesn't store the cookies, how do I enable them?

I used this code to test it:

```
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        webView.loadUrl("http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_cookie1");
```

After I reload (webView.reload()) the page I do see "Cookie 'user' is set!" but after I close the application and start it again I see "Cookie 'user' is NOT set!". Weirdly enough sometimes I do see it set when I first start the app. So what's going on here? Is there a delay when cookies are stored or am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that there is a delay indeed with the cookies so I have to use this code:

```
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
               public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                   CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Page loading complete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
        });
```

Now it works fine.

Comment: 6 years on, this is still the case. WebView cookies indeed don't get saved when the app is terminated too soon. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 6):

+1 for eXistenZ' answer, but now in 2020 `CookieSyncManager` is deprecated. Now you should use `CookieManager.getInstance().flush()` or write something like this:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
            } else {
                CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
            } 
        }
});
```

Comment: working like charm. Thanks :)))